# sifr 3 only visible on my computer

Tags: sifr, sifr3

I am using sifr3 in my website. I have uploaded the website on a real server and I realized that the sifr3 fonts are only visible when I'm browsing the page from my computer. I have uploaded all the essential files and I don't understand what might be broken. Can you help me please?

This is the link to the test website:
http://www.artabout.gr/idiston/

(look at the h1 headings, the menu is using images, not sifr)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to embed the font

http://www.bethinkerconcepts.com/2009/06/embedding-fonts/

Comment: thank you very much, I had used device fonts instead of anti-alias for animation.

Comment: No problem :) Welcome on stackoverflow! By the way, you can also "upvote" my answer while accepting it, it's always a nice thing to do (and most people on SO do it)